# Dividing amount in accordance to probability of winning.

Tags: probability

Two people, $A$ and $B$ put $100$ in a pot and tossed a coin. If heads,then $A$ gained a point,if tails,then $B$ gained a point. The $100$ were given to the person who got $10$ points.They had a problem-

$A$ needed $1$ points to win and $B$ needed $2$ points to win. 
How could they divide the $100$ now?
Answer:
$A$ had $\frac{3}{4}$ probability of winning and $B$ had $\frac{1}{4}$.
The $100$ were divided in accordance of this probability.- $A$ got $75$ and $B$ got $25$.

My problem is that if $A$ needs $2$ points and $B$ needs $4$ points,how do I divide the $100$ accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

$B$ will win if and only if in the next $5$ games there are more
than $3$ tails.

Probability based on binomial distribution: $$\left[\binom{5}{4}+\binom{5}{5}\right]2^{-5}=\frac{6}{32}=\frac{3}{16}$$

So his share should be $100\times\frac{3}{16}$